# When naming interfaces, is it a good name if the ending is the same as the package name?

Tags: go

Which name is better, `repository.UserRepository` or `repository.User`?

I'm thinking about naming recently.
I have referenced several sources and they are talking.

> Think about the context and name it.

Here is the link.

- https://talks.golang.org/2014/names.slide#2
- https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments

Additionally, Can you also recommend a project that can be referred to when creating an http server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [golang official ducument](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#package-names)

> The importer of a package will use the name to refer to its contents, so exported names in the package can use that fact to avoid stutter. (Don't use the import . notation, which can simplify tests that must run outside the package they are testing, but should otherwise be avoided.) For instance, the buffered reader type in the bufio package is called Reader, not BufReader, **because users see it as bufio.Reader, which is a clear, concise name**. Moreover, because imported entities are always addressed with their package name, bufio.Reader does not conflict with io.Reader.

repository.User may be good then repository.UserRepository

the package in src/encoding/base64 is imported as "encoding/base64" not "encoding/base64Encoding"